# Remove trailing 0s and decimal if necessary from string

Tags: c++, string, zero, decimal-point, trailing

I'm trying to remove trailing zeros from a decimal, removing the decimal if there are no more trailing zeros.

This string produced from a boost's `gmp_float` string output of fixed.

This is my attempt, but I'm getting `std::out_of_range`:

```
string trim_decimal( string toFormat ){
    while( toFormat.find(".") && toFormat.substr( toFormat.length() - 1, 1) == "0" || toFormat.substr( toFormat.length() - 1, 1) == "." ){
        toFormat.pop_back();
    }
    return toFormat;
}
```

How can I remove trailing `0`s if a decimal is present, removing the decimal if there are no more `0`s after the decimal point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change it to:

```
while( toFormat.find(".")!=string::npos   // !=string::npos is important!!!
    && toFormat.substr( toFormat.length() - 1, 1) == "0" 
    || toFormat.substr( toFormat.length() - 1, 1) == "." )
{
    toFormat.pop_back();
}
```

The key here is to add **`!=string::npos`**. When not found, [`std::basic_string::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) will return [`std::basic_string::npos`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos), which is not equal to `false` (not what you expect).

```
static const size_type npos = -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    auto lastNotZeroPosition = stringValue.find_last_not_of('0');
    if (lastNotZeroPosition != std::string::npos && lastNotZeroPosition + 1 < stringValue.size())
    {
        //We leave 123 from 123.0000 or 123.3 from 123.300
        if (stringValue.at(lastNotZeroPosition) == '.')
        {
            --lastNotZeroPosition;
        }
        stringValue.erase(lastNotZeroPosition + 1, std::string::npos);
    }
```

In C++ you have [std::string::find_last_not_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_not_of/)